# Synonimise [ironkingdoms] to [iron-kingdoms]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

This is pretty small, but [a recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28166/is-the-iron-kingdoms-entry-adventure-intentionally-easy) created the [ironkingdoms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ironkingdoms) tag. Normally we put a hyphen for the space in a tag's name, so it should be [iron-kingdoms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-kingdoms).

I would make this change myself but I can't! I get this error message whilst trying to change the tag on the question:

[image: Error message reading: "You are attempting to create the tag iron-kingdoms; however the tag ironkingdoms already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.]

So, here I am. Can we change it?

Comment: That's an "interesting" new feature. I can see why they would add it, but it's a bit of a pain, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed that one answer and made a synonym.

Comment: Thanks for that. :)